# Type hints for classes implementing an interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Suppose I have an interface `A` with a single function.

```
class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def spam(self, x: int) -> str:
        pass
```

There are classes `B` and `C` that implement this interface, but they will not be directly initialized. I will have some factory method (say) that will return to me a suitable object implementing `A`. So in this case, when I implement `spam` in `B` and `C`, should I repeat the type hints? Practically, since `B` and `C` aren't directly used, the type hints for `A` seem sufficient. But I'm curious about the best practice in this situation; and if there are other issues to be considered.

Comment: if you're performing static analysis, the safest option is to supply hints everywhere. This question really depends on how static analyzers are implemented, I don't believe that any analyzers will realize that your class implements an abstractmethod and, as a result, use the types supplied there.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087885/static-type-check-for-abstract-method-in-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183424/can-a-python-abstract-base-class-enforce-function-signatures

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, since you implement `B.spam`, it won't be a trivial implementation (otherwise, why bother overriding `A.spam`?). So you probably should type check the body of `B.spam`. In that case, you need to provide type hints for the arguments and return values of `B.spam`; otherwise, mypy will treat those types as `Any`.

Note that if you do provide type hints, mypy will check that the type of `B.spam` is compatible with `A.spam` using its [rules for subclassing](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/class_basics.html#overriding-statically-typed-methods), but *only* if `B` derives from `A` non-virtually; if you just `A.register(B)`, mypy will ignore the inheritance relationship entirely. This is consistent with how the runtime will not look up `.spam` in the virtual base classes.

Comment: Any clarification as to why my answer is wrong would be welcome.