# Static type check for abstract method in Python

Tags: python, pycharm

How do I make sure that a method implementing an abstract method adheres to the python static type checks. Is there a way in pycharm to get an error if the return type is incorrect for the implemented method?

```
class Dog:
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def bark(self) -> str:
        raise NotImplementedError("A dog must bark")

class Chihuahua(Dog):
    def bark(self):
        return 123
```

So for the above code I would want to get some sort of a hint that there is something wrong with my chihuahua

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: I think today the right answer would be to use a static type checker like [`mypy`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/). There's a [mypy plugin for JetBrains IDEs](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11086-mypy).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No there's not a (simple) way to enforce this.

And actually there isn't anything wrong with your `Chihuahua` as Python's duck typing allows you to override the signature (both arguments and types) of `bark`. So `Chihuahua.bark` returning an `int` is completely valid code (although not necessarily good practice as it violates [the LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). Using the `abc` module doesn't change this at all as [it doesn't enforce method signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183424/can-a-python-abstract-base-class-enforce-function-signatures).

To "enforce" the type simply carry across the type hint to the new method, which makes it explicit. It also results in PyCharm showing a warning.

```
import abc

class Dog:
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def bark(self) -> str:
        raise NotImplementedError("A dog must bark")

class Chihuahua(Dog):
    def bark(self) -> str:
        # PyCharm warns against the return type
        return 123
```